# Error compiling expo-modules-core with gradlew

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, cmake, expo

When running `npx expo run:android`, the Gradle compile process fails at "Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]" with the following error:

```
C/C++: CMake Error at D:/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
C/C++:   The C compiler
C/C++:     "D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"
C/C++:   is not able to compile a simple test program.
C/C++:   It fails with the following output:
C/C++:     Change Dir: D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
C/C++:
C/C++:     Run Build Command(s):D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe cmTC_5e76d && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
C/C++:     [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_5e76d
C/C++:     FAILED: cmTC_5e76d
C/C++:     cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_5e76d  -latomic -lm && cd ."
C/C++:     clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o'
C/C++:     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
C/C++:
C/C++:
C/C++:
C/C++:   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
C/C++: Call Stack (most recent call first):
C/C++:   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)

> Task :expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:configureCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a]'.
> [CXX1429] error when building with cmake using D:\source\repos\Project\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android\CMakeLists.txt: -- The C compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 17.0.2
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe - broken
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

  C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
      @echo off
      "D:\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
        "-HD:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android" ^
        "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
        "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
        "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=21" ^
        "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21" ^
        "-DANDROID_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DANDROID_NDK=D:\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125" ^
        "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=D:\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125" ^
        "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\26.1.10909125\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
        "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.22.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
        "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\406o3g4y\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\406o3g4y\\obj\\arm64-v8a" ^
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
        "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\406o3g4y\\prefab\\arm64-v8a\\prefab" ^
        "-BD:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\.cxx\\Debug\\406o3g4y\\arm64-v8a" ^        -GNinja ^
        "-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared" ^
        "-DREACT_NATIVE_DIR=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\react-native" ^
        "-DREACT_NATIVE_SO_DIR=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\build/react/jni" ^
        "-DREACT_NATIVE_TARGET_VERSION=72" ^
        "-DBOOST_VERSION=1_76_0" ^
        "-DUSE_HERMES=false" ^
        "-DHERMES_HEADER_DIR=null" ^
        "-DIS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED=false" ^
        "-DPROJECT_BUILD_DIR=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\expo-modules-core\\android\\build" ^
        "-DREACT_ANDROID_DIR=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\react-native/ReactAndroid" ^
        "-DREACT_ANDROID_BUILD_DIR=D:\\source\\repos\\Project\\node_modules\\react-native/ReactAndroid/build" ^
        "-DUNIT_TEST=false"
    from D:\source\repos\Project\node_modules\expo-modules-core\android
  CMake Error at D:/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
    The C compiler

      "D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe"

    is not able to compile a simple test program
    It fails with the following output:

      Change Dir: D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

      Run Build Command(s):D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe cmTC_5e76d && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
      [2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_5e76d
      FAILED: cmTC_5e76d
      cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_5e76d  -latomic -lm && cd ."
      clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_5e76d.dir/testCCompiler.c.o'
      ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
```

The error from the CMake logs:

```
Detecting C compiler ABI info failed to compile with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe cmTC_41963 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_41963.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o

Android (10552028, based on r487747d) clang version 17.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project d9f89f4d16663d5012e5c09495f3b30ece3d2362)

Target: aarch64-none-linux-android21

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin

 (in-process)

 "D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang.exe" -cc1 -triple aarch64-none-linux-android21 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name CMakeCCompilerABI.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -pic-is-pie -mframe-pointer=non-leaf -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -funwind-tables=2 -target-cpu generic -target-feature +neon -target-feature +v8a -target-feature +fix-cortex-a53-835769 -target-abi aapcs -mllvm -treat-scalable-fixed-error-as-warning -debug-info-kind=constructor -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fcoverage-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -resource-dir D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17 -dependency-file "CMakeFiles\\cmTC_41963.dir\\CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o.d" -MT CMakeFiles/cmTC_41963.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -sys-header-deps -D ANDROID -D _FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -isysroot D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -internal-isystem D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17/include -internal-isystem D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/local/include -internal-externc-isystem D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -internal-externc-isystem D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/include -internal-externc-isystem D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -Wformat -fdebug-compilation-dir=D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 2 -fno-signed-char -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -target-feature +outline-atomics -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_41963.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -x c D:/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.22.1/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeCCompilerABI.c

clang -cc1 version 17.0.2 based upon LLVM 17.0.2 default target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu

ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/local/include"

ignoring nonexistent directory "D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/include"

#include "..." search starts here:

#include <...> search starts here:

 D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/clang/17/include

 D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android

 D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include

End of search list.

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_41963

FAILED: cmTC_41963 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments   -v CMakeFiles/cmTC_41963.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o -o cmTC_41963   && cd ."

Android (10552028, based on r487747d) clang version 17.0.2 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project d9f89f4d16663d5012e5c09495f3b30ece3d2362)

Target: aarch64-none-linux-android21

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_41963.dir/CMakeCCompilerABI.c.o'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.





Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: D:/source/repos/Project/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/.cxx/Debug/406o3g4y/arm64-v8a/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.22.1\bin\ninja.exe cmTC_8ce57 && [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ce57.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

[2/2] Linking C executable cmTC_8ce57

FAILED: cmTC_8ce57 

cmd.exe /C "cd . && D:\Android\Sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang.exe --target=aarch64-none-linux-android21 --sysroot=D:/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/sysroot -g -DANDROID -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,--build-id=sha1 -Wl,--no-rosegment -Wl,--no-undefined-version -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Qunused-arguments CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ce57.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_8ce57  -latomic -lm && cd ."

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_8ce57.dir/testCCompiler.c.o'

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This happens in any React Native/Expo project, including fresh ones or after deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm i`. I have tried reinstalling CMake, the SDK, and all other tools in Android Studio already. `expo-doctor` returns no issues, and `npx react-native doctor` does not fix anything.